# Create custom terminal boot mode under ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub2

I wonder if it would be possible to create a custom boot menu entry in grub under Ubuntu (11.04), that boots the system into terminal instead of the login screen.

The effect should be something like the root shell in `(rescue mode)` boot menu entry, one that gives me access to a root shell or a less privileged shell, without the need to select "root shell" explicitly.

If possible, I also would like to customize the shell started by, most preferably by specifying a shell script to run so that I can start something other than bash, like vim.

My intention is to create a "fast" boot mode to give me a usable system within seconds (to take notes, for instance) without needing to start GUI. Therefore, it is preferred that the `silent` option is turned on.

**Note:** There is a requirement: that no existing feature of the system is removed. That is to say, the gnome desktop (and Unity) should remain intact, and is only disabled when I choose this mode.

Comment: you could try askubuntu.com (another SE site) for your future questions.

Comment: @Chris J. Lee: Oh, thanks. looks like I didn't look through the stackexchange websites too carefully. Plus, I've never had a good impression about forums, which incidentally, includes ubuntuforums. Possibly gave me a biased view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would test it on a VM or something first if I were you (GRUB2 a scary scary thing) but according to [this blog post](http://ubuntuguide.net/boot-into-consolecommand-line-when-startup-ubuntu-9-10) it shouldn't be harder than changing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash text”
```

in `/etc/default/grub`. This has the side effect of forcing you to run `startx` in order to start x.

Another solution I found would be simply to disable `gdm` from Ubuntu's services list in Preferences.

Comment: good idea, and I was wondering if I should use kernel switches. I'll try this then. And thanks for the warning, but I think I've used ubuntu long enough to get myself out of a grub configuration disaster. I've got a lot of sysrescuecd's around. I think I'll use a custom menunentry instead of modifying the default (/etc/grub.d/40_Custom).

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can get to solve the problem based on one answer.

The final solution is:

1. Create a custom menuentry in `/etc/grub.d/40_Custom` with the kernel option `text` turn on to prevent auto-start of gdm as I wish, therefore boosting start up speed.
2. Create a under-privileged user `<user name>` (I personally chose to block its access to my home directory using acl, strip it of administrative permissions and use a bogus password that no one can remember.)
3. Edit `/etc/init/tty2.conf` to enable auto log in:

   1. Change `exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2` to `exec /sbin/getty -l <path to logon script> -8 38400 tty2`
   2. In file `<path to logon script>` add the following lines:

      ```
      #!/bin/sh
      login -f <user name>
      ```
   3. Execute `sudo chown root:root <path to logon script>`
   4. Execute `sudo chmod 755 <path to logon script>`
4. If you'd like to rapidly take notes with vim in tty2, then (skip if you don't know what vim is)

   1. Install vim
   2. Install the [notes.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3375) plugin for vim
   3. Log in as `<user name>` and add the following lines to `~/.bashrc`

      ```
      vim -c :RecentNotes
      ```

Remember to replace the things in angular brackets with corresponding values.